# How to resize an image by keeping its aspect ration in Windows phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, aspect-ratio

I want to resize the image that I am going to display by keeping its aspect ratio.

How can I achieve that. ?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myImage = new Image();
        Uri uri = new Uri("Penguins.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        bit = new BitmapImage(uri);

        myImage.Source = bit;
        imagePanel.Children.Add(myImage);
    }
```

Here the image is stored in the variable bit. How can I resize it by keeping its aspect ratio ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Stretch` property in `Image` class. You can set `None`, `Uniform` or `UniformToFill` to keep aspect ratio when image is resized in order to fill image area

Comment: will it keep image's aspect ratio ?

Comment: Yes, only `Fill` will resize your image to fill all area